# Embedding another video to "blend" with the environment

Tags: video, video-editor, editing, software, effects

Suppose I have a mirror, or a picture on the wall, and I want to run a second video into this.

How could that be achieved? And even in such a way as to correct for perspective?

For example, like in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7i3DxuyTQbU#t=4m14s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use a tool like Apple's Motion or FCPX, or Adobe's After Effects, they all have the ability to put the 4 corners of a layer anywhere you want. With Motion or After Effects, you can even track the 4 corners and keep the "TV" image pinned in the right place.

In [Motion](https://help.apple.com/motion/mac/5.3/), you can select a clip and open the Inspector. In the Inspector, press the "Properties" tab. There's a section in the properties called "Four Corner". If you twirl that open, it allows you to set where the 4 corners of the video go. You can put them wherever you like.

[FCPX](https://help.apple.com/finalcutpro/mac/10.3/) is similar - select the clip, and open the inspector. There should be a section in the inspector named "Distort". This will also let you set the 4 corners of the clip.

In [After Effects](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/layer-properties.html) you can select a layer and apply the built-in "Corner Pin" effect.

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be accomplished using the "picture-in-picture" feature of most editing software. I've used Adobe Premiere and iMovie, and both include that feature.  Premiere has the advantage that you can "mask" a layer, so it is not quite rectangular, in order to fit the shape of the mirror.

Make sure the camera for the main scene is on a tripod and does not move at all. If that camera moves, you will need to animate your picture-in-picture video and mask so it appears to stay inside the mirror's frame.